# CRUD FBA users through CSOM or powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, asp.net

For a web application configured with OOTB FBA membership, is there possible to manage the list (stored in asp membership) of users through CSOM or maybe PowerShell ? I'm looking to see if any documented way of modifying (deleting/updating) the users within the FBA database without querying the database directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSOM does not provide this functionality. You will need to connect to the database or find middleware such as an identity governance solution to manage accounts within the FBA database.